# Adjusting Bright makes Ubuntu not to respond

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, screen, brightness

Have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and when adjusting the bright through the keyboard Ubuntu gets frozen and needs to be restarted by forcing the turnoff button, have noticed that this only happens when pressing the bright key fastly so need to press the key once then wait a few seconds and then press again, windows 7 is also installed in the same machine and is able to set the bright correctly and it does not matter how fast i press the key, someone can help me in how to solve this issue, thanks in advance.-

Answer (score 0):

Install xbacklight:

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

You can set brightness to X% as (no sudo required):

```
xbacklight -set X
```

To make the setting permanent, go to Startup Applications and add a new startup program, with the following command (where X% is your desired brightness):

```
xbacklight -set X
```

example : `xbacklight -set 65`

[image]

Next time, you log in to your computer, Brightness will automatically set to 65. You can change this value any time.